# Turn an entire SceneKit scene into an image suitable for a texture

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I've written a little app using CoreMotion, AV and SceneKit to make a simple panorama. When you take a picture, it maps that onto a SK rectangle and places it in front of whatever CM direction the camera is facing. This is working fine, but...

I would like the user to be able to click a "done" button and turn the entire scene into a single image. I could then map that onto a sphere for future viewing rather than re-creating the entire set of objects. I don't need to stitch or anything like that, I want the individual images to remain separate rectangles, like photos glued to the inside of a ball.

I know about `snapshot` and tried using that with a really wide FOV, but that results in a fisheye view that does not map back properly (unless I'm doing it wrong). I assume there is some sort of transform I need to apply? Or perhaps there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The key is "photos glued to the inside of a ball". You have a bunch of rectangles, suspended in space. Turning that into one image suitable for projection onto a sphere is a bit of work. You'll have to project each rectangle onto the sphere, and warp the image accordingly.

If you just want to reconstruct the scene for future viewing in SceneKit, use SCNScene's built in serialization, `write(to:​options:​delegate:​progress​Handler:​)` and `SCNScene(named:)`.

To compute the mapping of images onto a sphere, you'll need some coordinate conversion. For each image, convert the coordinates of the corners into spherical coordinates, with the origin at your point of view. Change the radius of each corner's coordinate to the radius of your sphere, and you now have the projected corners' locations on the sphere.

It's tempting to repeat this process for each pixel in the input rectangular image. But that will leave empty pixels in the spherical output image. So you'll work in reverse. For each pixel in the spherical output image (within the 4 corner points), compute the ray (trivially done, in spherical coordinates) from POV to that point. Convert that ray back to Cartesian coordinates, compute its intersection with the rectangular image's plane, and sample at that point in your input image. You'll want to do some pixel weighting, since your output image and input image will have different pixel dimensions.

Comment: Do you have pointers that discuss this mapping? I do want to make a single image, that way I can also process it.